# Codeigniter Pagination Broken link

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm trying to build a sample webpage for a story. Contains About/TableofContents/Reviews(div - divided into 3 rows in that order)

```
$num_rows = $this->story_model->count_rows('chapters',$story_id, null);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'story/story_profile/'.$story_id.'/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = '0';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $offset = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $data['chapters'] = $this->db->get_where('chapters', array('story_id' => $story_id), $config['per_page'],$offset);
```

I chose segment(4) is because i used the 3rd segment to specify which profile i am viewing. I used pagination like this on segment(3) and it works fine. Why is it going haywire when i used segment(4)? i also plan to use segment(5) to paginate another set of data so if it is causing me trouble at segment(4) idk what will happen if i added another pagination using segment(5).

I'll try to explain the error as best as i can, Say i have 10 rows in my data and i want to desplay 5 per page so my link should be = **[1]**[2](bold meaning selected, first page is always selected at initial loading)

The problem is that whenever i load my page, the highlighted link is the last one([2], if i used 2 data per page resulting in links 1-5 the link that is highlighted is [5]). The first and the last link is broken in this case. If for example with my 10 data and i used 5 per page then my whole link is broken but if i used a smaller number so that there are links in between the first and last then those links work fine. the fist and last link will also work so long as i clicked on those links before.

In any case, i think it has something to do with my uri segment coz if i manually edited the segment(for example for page 1 i'd put 0 in my segment(4)) then the pagination works. Also if i click on the last link my segment(4) becomes '#'.

Idk whats the problem since it works either way if i used segment(3). idk why its causing problems with 4.

Comment: Okay. so i added this line of code.

$config['uri_segment'] = 4;

and it seems to be working fine but idk why????? i saw another question for this on another question and it seems for them it was not working but it was years ago so idk if it was fixed? Maybe the pagination assumes the segment is 3 without clicking on any link thats why my first and last is broken?

Comment: I'll try it out first with another pagination for segment(5) and see if it works.

Comment: whats your question ?

Comment: I just solved it but in any case my question was why was segment(4) and possibly above going haywire with my code above. And i solved it because i added $config['uri_segment'] = 4. line to my current code i guess pagination class assumed it was 3 i guess thats the default?

Comment: `$this->uri->segment(4);` will not work in your case? you know it right ?

Comment: Huh? that was my initial question because it had problems. It worked but the first and last link on the pagination links were broken.